# Installing Twain Module in 64 bit Windows and Use Python

Tags: python, twain

I have 64 bit Windows and 64 bit Python . I want to install twain in my machine . So I have download [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-dsm/) . I did what readme file said . Copied twaindsm.dll into system32 and SysWow64 file. Then I have used twain like I said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855258/using-twain-module-in-python?noredirect=1#comment57450358_34855258) . Then I test if the driver is installed .So for this purpose I download [twacker](http://kb.dynamsoft.com/questions/644/How+to+use+TWACKER+to+check+if+my+device+is+TWAIN+Compliant%3F). In the [twacker](http://kb.dynamsoft.com/questions/644/How+to+use+TWACKER+to+check+if+my+device+is+TWAIN+Compliant%3F) when I execute the 32 bit :
[image]

I can see my scanner devices and connect to it . When I execute the 64 bit :
[image]

There are no scanner device to connect and this result is the same like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855258/using-twain-module-in-python?noredirect=1#comment57450358_34855258) . So the problem is 64 bit twain does not installed correct ? If so how can I install because I download [twain 64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-dsm/) . Pls anyone help me ?

Answer (score -2):

**Cause of the Problem**

The main reason is that most scanner vendors only support 32bit TWAIN driver.

**Solution to Access Scanners in 64 Applications**

[Asprise Scanning SDK is probably the only scanning library that works for both 64bit and 32bit applications](http://asprise.com/c%23-vb.net-scanner-api/twain-wia-scan-pdf-library-overview.html) thanks to the innovative patent pending technology and quality implementation.